# Joomla 3 tinymce frontend textarea input

Tags: textarea, virtuemart, tinymce-4, joomla3.4

I'm trying to build a virtuemart custom field for customers using the joomla 3 integrated tinymce editor (v 4.1.7) as a textarea input.
The problem is, after I enter the text in tinymce, when I add the product to cart, I get the html raw source code (the text input is delimited by quotes).
I think is a Joomla 3 issue, because I tried also with Joomla 2.5 and I get the correct formatted text.
Does anybody have an idea why this issue is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I supposed, it was a Joomla filtering problem.
Looks like for Joomla 3.5 the plugin works ok.
I don't know what was exactly the issue, but I'm glad now is solved.
For anyone interested, you can see the plugin in action at: http://virtuemart-textarea.mcprowebdesign.uk/

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.

Answer (score -1):

Joomla always filters your input. You would need to make changes to your field (or the editor settings) to change how things are filtered.